# How to build a devise nested resource during registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

During registration of a new user with Devise, I need to create a new Family object link to this new user at the same time (the user being the head of the family).

My family model:

```
belongs_to user
```

My user model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :family
has_one :family
accepts_nested_attributes_for :family
```

In devise/registration/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([resource, Family.new], :as => resource_name, :url =>     registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= display_base_errors resource %>
  <%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>

  <% f.fields_for :family do |family_form| %>
    <p><%= family_form.label :name %></p>
    <p><%= family_form.text_field :name %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit, 'OK', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

But this is not working, I find a couple of question like this but I did not manage to fix that.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE 1**

I got the following error:

```
undefined method `email' for #<Family:0x007f892a12c310>
```

Family is a model that do not have any email, just a name. I just need to be able to create a new Family object with a name when creating a new user (and link it to the user as well).

**UPDATE 2**

I have added resource.build_family in my registrations controller. The family object is correctly created and associated to the user (I can display <%= resource.family %> in new.html.erb for debugging), but still no form displayed for the family.

Comment: Can you post the log output from your rails s session when a user registers?

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated the question.

Comment: Actually what I wanted to see from the log was the details of the request.  It is clear that the problem is what is being submitted by the form and the log will show the form parameter hash.

Comment: In fact, the inner form (the family one) is not even displayed during the registration of a new user.

Comment: Ok, but from your log extract it indicates that the Update Attributes function is getting a param of Email and passing it to the Family object.  So lets see what is in the request and we can see what the controller is processing.

Comment: USing the registration controller and the build_family, I do not have any more error. Just the Family form is not displayed when registrating a new user.

Comment: How/where did you add `resource.build_family` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need the equal sign in the <%=fields_for

```
<%= f.fields_for :family do |family_form| %>
    <p><%= family_form.label :name %></p>
    <p><%= family_form.text_field :name %></p>
  <% end %>
```

And in your user model you need to make the :family_attribues accessible and not :family

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :family_attributes
has_one :family
accepts_nested_attributes_for :family
```

Comment: That is much better like this, the form is displayed. Sorry for this stupid error. When I validate the form, I now have an error message: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Family(#70201211296680) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70201188285920)

Comment: Have adjusted the answer based on your last comment.  Any chance of the question being accepted :-)

Comment: I still have the same error (AssociationTypeMismatch), seems to be linked to resource = build_resource(params[:user]) line

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `undefined method 'email' for #<Model:0x007f892a12c310>`:

You need to overwrite `Devise::RegistrationsController` as described in the docs: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers. E.g.

```rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super do |resource|
      resource.build_<model>
    end
  end
end
```

And you must only specify `resource` in `form_for`: `simple_form_for(resource, ...` instead of `simple_form_for([resource, Model.new], ...`